# No podspec found for 'myapp' in '.symlinks/plugins/myapp/ios'

Tags: swift, flutter, bitrise

Differently from other similar questions, the build in my case fails because the podspec was not found for **my own app**, while other similar issues happen with third-party dependencies.

Basically, the build on my MacOS works fine, but when running it in a CI tool (Bitrise), it fails with the following error:

```
...
-> Fetching podspec for `itini` from `.symlinks/plugins/itini/ios`
[!] No podspec found for `itini` in `.symlinks/plugins/itini/ios`
```

I already tried (without success):

- Build without Podfile.lock;
- Run `pod install` before the build step;

Flutter info's log:

```
Flutter 2.2.2 • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision d79295af24 (5 days ago) • 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
Engine • revision 91c9fc8fe0
Tools • Dart 2.13.3
```

Full error's log:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| (5) flutter-build@0.13                                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id: flutter-build                                                            |
| version: 0.13.3                                                              |
| collection: https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise-steplib.git                |
| toolkit: go                                                                  |
| time: 2021-06-16T21:48:33Z                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                              |
Config:
- IOSAdditionalParams: --release --no-codesign
- AndroidAdditionalParams: --release
- Platform: ios
- IOSExportPattern: *build/ios/iphoneos/*.app
- AndroidOutputType: apk
- AndroidExportPattern: *build/app/outputs/apk/*/*.apk
*build/app/outputs/bundle/*/*.aab
- IOSCodesignIdentity: 
- ProjectLocation: /Users/vagrant/git
- DebugMode: false
- CacheLevel: all
- AndroidBundleExportPattern: *build/app/outputs/bundle/*/*.aab
iOS Codesign settings
 - Skipping codesign preparation, --no-codesign parameter set
Build iOS
$ flutter "build" "ios" "--release" "--no-codesign"
Downloading Material fonts...                                      630ms
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...                                       15ms
Downloading package sky_engine...                                  142ms
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...                           334ms
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk_product tools...                   289ms
Downloading darwin-x64 tools...                                  2,444ms
Downloading libimobiledevice...                                     24ms
Downloading usbmuxd...                                              12ms
Downloading libplist...                                             11ms
Downloading openssl...                                             151ms
Downloading ios-deploy...                                           12ms
Downloading darwin-x64/font-subset tools...                        201ms
Downloading ios tools...                                         2,706ms
Downloading ios-profile tools...                                 2,060ms
Downloading ios-release tools...                                   12.8s
Running "flutter pub get" in git...                                11.1s
Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building me.itini.mobile for device (ios-release)...
Running pod install...                                           1,832ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Finding Podfile changes
      A itini
      - Flutter
      - appsflyer_sdk
      - connectivity_plus
      - device_info
      - firebase_analytics
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - firebase_messaging
      - firebase_performance
      - flutter_facebook_auth
      - flutter_local_notifications
      - flutter_secure_storage
      - fluttertoast
      - geocoding
      - geolocator
      - google_maps_flutter
      - google_sign_in
      - package_info
      - package_info_plus
      - path_provider
      - permission_handler
      - search_choices
      - sentry_flutter
      - share
      - shared_preferences
      - sign_in_with_apple
      - url_launcher
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `appsflyer_sdk` from `.symlinks/plugins/appsflyer_sdk/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `connectivity_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `device_info` from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
    firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
    firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_performance` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_performance/ios`
    firebase_performance: Using Firebase SDK version '8.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_facebook_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_local_notifications` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_local_notifications/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_secure_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_secure_storage/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `fluttertoast` from `.symlinks/plugins/fluttertoast/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `geocoding` from `.symlinks/plugins/geocoding/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `geolocator` from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_maps_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `itini` from `.symlinks/plugins/itini/ios`
    [!] No podspec found for `itini` in `.symlinks/plugins/itini/ios`
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:14:in `block in fetch'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:989:in `fetch_external_source'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:968:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:967:in `each'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:967:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:966:in `fetch_external_sources'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:117:in `analyze'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```